# framer.js studio PSD

Tags: javascript, prototype, framerjs

So I am new framer.js and just imported a psd into the framer studio. The import went fine and I can see all my layers on the right I am just not sure how to target them. Lets say I have a layer named "footer" in my psd file, to target it would I just do something like:

```
footer.visible = false
```

When I do I get an error of `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: footer`

All the videos and tutorials I find online seem a little older and are not using the Framer Studio so they do not help. Any insight??

Comment: You get that error because the variable `footer` doesn't exists.

Comment: Ya I messed around a little more and got it dialed. It imports the psd like `ly = Framer.Importer.load "imported/filters"` so to call footer I just used `ly.footer`

Comment: You should post it as an answer. I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work you look what Framer imported the psd as and use that for the first part of the variable and the second part is the folder name so if the import was

```
PSD = Framer.Importer.load("imported/mypsdfile")
```

then to call it would be

```
PSD.footer.visible = false
```